# SQL Server using IIF in Where Clause Syntax Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax, sql-server-2014, iif

I'm using SQL Server 2014. I keep getting a red squiggly lines under the last `=` sign and last parenthesis:

```
DECLARE @I_sYear char(4); 
SET @I_sYear = '2021'

SELECT
    PriceType,
    SUM(PriceAmount) AS PriceAmount,
    DATEPART(YEAR, PostedDate) AS year,
    DATEPART(MONTH, PostedDate) AS month
FROM 
    Stage
WHERE
    IIF(ISNULL(@I_sYear, '') = '', 1, DATEPART(YEAR, PostedDate) = @I_sYear)
```

But if I don't use the `IIF` and just use `Where DATEPART(YEAR, PostedDate) = @I_sYear` it works fine.

Basically I'm just trying to evaluate if a year was passed in and if so use that year, if not select all rows.

What is the reason for that syntax error?

Comment: Simply use regular AND/OR instead.

Comment: I mean, what's the last argument of the `IIF` supposed to do?, it's another comparison

Comment: In order to be able to do `WHERE IIF()` then `IIF` would need to be able to return a boolean datatype. It can't. SQL Server doesn't support SQL Boolean datatype. Even if SQL Server did support that this would be an inefficient and unreadable mess. The apparently desired semantics would be clearer as ``@I_sYear IS NULL OR @I_sYear = '' OR  DATEPART(YEAR, PostedDate) = @I_sYear`` and then that shows this is a "catch all" query anti pattern

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the final argument to `IIF()`:

```
DATEPART(YEAR, PostedDate) = @I_sYear
```

This has two issues. First, the `DATEPART()` result is an `int`, but the code tries to compare it with a `varchar`. You have to cast one side or the other so the types match.

Second, it's trying to represent a boolean result as `1` or `0`, to match with the `1` from the prior `IIF()` argument. SQL Server will not do that.

You need a `CASE` expression to get the 1 or 0 result, but again: for SQL, *that's not the same as boolean*. Thankfully, we can simplify this even further:

```
WHERE DATEPART(YEAR, PostedDate) = COALESCE(Cast(@I_sYear As int), DATEPART(YEAR, PostedDate))
```

No `IIF()` or `CASE` involved at all, and this could be even simpler, faster, and safer if you're open to declaring `@I_sYear` as an int in the first place:

```
WHERE DATEPART(YEAR, PostedDate) = COALESCE(@I_sYear, DATEPART(YEAR, PostedDate))
```

Comment: `WHERE @I_sYear IS NULL OR (PostedDate >= DATEFROMPARTS(@I_sYear, 1, 1) AND PostedDate < DATEFROMPARTS(@I_sYear + 1, 1, 1)` might be more efficient, although the `OR is going to cause problems whatever you do. Dynamic SQL might be the solution here.